# Multiple parents of a theme

Tags: magento2, theme-fallback, parent-child-theme

In Magento 2, it is possible to [extend themes by inheritance](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html).

Is it possible to have *more* than 1 parent theme?

Comment: You can use one theme as your parent theme. and then on your parent theme add another parent theme

Comment: Thanks @AsishHira , but that will couple these 2 themes (one of them will have the other as a parent). Which is just what I'm trying to avoid :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't have multiple parents. That would make inheritance very messy. If both parents had the same template, which would take precedence?

As Asish said, all you can do is make use of multiple-level inheritance. Theme A can't extend Theme B and Theme C simultaneously, but Theme A can extend Theme B which extends Theme C.

Works:

`Theme A > Theme B > Theme C`

Does not work:

`Theme A > Theme B` +
`Theme A > Theme C`

Comment: Worth also adding you can have infinite theme fallback with Magento 1.